# How to convert Int to String and vice versa in c++ (without using libraries like sstream)

Tags: c++, string, type-conversion, int

For my university computer science course, our professor wants us to use a method of converting a string to an int (and int to string) without the use of any libraries such as sstream. I can't exactly find it anywhere in the notes/online and am hoping someone could show/tell me what it is and tell me how afterwards I would know that it has successfully been converted. All I know is that it involves using static_cast and also ASCII. He went over it quickly in class and I copied the code down quickly so there's a chance I could be missing something important or mistyped something, but here's what I got.

```
void intToStr(){
    string numString = "2019";
    int num = 0;
    for(int i =0; i < numString.length(); i++){
        char c = numString[i];
        num = num * 10 + static_cast<int>(c) - static_cast<int>('0');
    }
}
```

Comment: A string is just a bunch of characters. You can easily convert a character to an int, `- '0'`, and vice versa for converting an int to character, `+ '0'`.

Comment: This seems absolutely correct, apart from being `StrToInt` and not returning `num`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to create c as a char as that adds an extra step for conversion and can look overwhelming with static_cast

c++ will assign the ASCII value for a char if you assign it to an int so for example the char version of '2' has an ascii code of 50 to get it's integer value you subtract the char version of '0' as that is the first ascii value corresponding to digits, similarily if you want to get the number value of a letter say you're doing something like converting a string to a number you would first assign the letter to an int to get its ascii value and subtract the char 'a' or 'A' depending on what case you are working with and it would return that letters index in the alphabet, below is the code demonstrating what i'm taling about for numbers

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int main(){
    string numString = "2019";
    int num = 0;
    for(int i =0; i < numString.size(); i++){
        int c = numString[i] -'0';
        cout << c << endl;
        num = num * 10 + c;
    }
    cout << num << endl;
}
```

Comment: How would I do this for converting an int to a string?

Comment: same process, chop each int off using integer division and then store that in a char and add either 'a' or 'A' depending on lower or upper

Comment: What would my code look like though since an integer can't be processed the same way such as finding the length of it for my for loop or like an array?

Comment: change you loop such that you keep working while (numberToParse!= 0)

Comment: and what about since an int cant be treated like an array. Could you write out the code for it so I can see it?

Comment: `using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char c = ' ';
    int i = 0;
    int num = 1234;
    while (num != 0){
    i = num%10;
    num = num/10;
    c = '0' + i;
    cout << i << " "  << num << " " << c <<  endl;
    }
    
}
`

Comment: I ran that code and it gave me a really weird output, definetely not the integer as a string.